# unable to start node-inspector

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

I have recently installed node-inspector using command `sudo npm install -g node-inspector` for debugging my node app. It is installed successfully. But when i run the command `node-inspector` it give me the following error:

```
debug.color = selectColor(namespae);
ReferenceError: namespae is not defined
at createDebug (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/node_modules/debug/debug.js:126:29)
```

I googled for this error, but doesn't find any solution.

Comment: Are you sure this is spelled right `namespae`?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in one of your dependencies. Hopefully someone will fix it soon. They are aware of it.

https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/347

Answer (score 0):

i think it is easier to use vs code to debug node.js instead of using node-inspector.

please read doc here 
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging